# How to prepare for Intense hiking after not exercising

Tags: running-training-plan

Under very short notice I decided to go along with some friends to Bozeman, Montana for an intense hiking trip in two weeks from now. We're talking 20 - 25 mile hikes in the mountains.

I am a bit muscular, but very out of shape and even obese. I've never really hiked that intensely before, especially in the mountains, nor got into a true running routine.

How, if practically possible, can I prepare for this trip in two weeks, confident that I won't hurt myself?

Comment: Do you work on your feet? If not I'm not sure it's possible without intense blisters.

Comment: I do walk a lot, is that enough?

Comment: How much is a lot? 20 miles in the mountains will be 8+ hours.